# Multiple files found for the same tablespace

Tags: mysql

how to fix this error?

```
2021-11-22T19:40:23.065929Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] c:\openserver\modules\database\MySQL-8.0-Win10\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.24) starting as process 4892
2021-11-22T19:40:23.076800Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-11-22T19:40:23.123029Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012209] [InnoDB] Multiple files found for the same tablespace ID:
2021-11-22T19:40:23.123125Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012202] [InnoDB] Tablespace ID: 50 = ['alexincube\wp_yoast_indexable.ibd', 'wordpressdb\wp_usermeta.ibd'] 
2021-11-22T19:40:23.123217Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012202] [InnoDB] Tablespace ID: 52 = ['alexincube\wp_yoast_primary_term.ibd', 'wordpressdb\wp_terms.ibd'] 
2021-11-22T19:40:23.123895Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Failed, retry may succeed.
2021-11-22T19:40:23.124010Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2021-11-22T19:40:23.124314Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2021-11-22T19:40:23.124446Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-11-22T19:40:23.125191Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] c:\openserver\modules\database\MySQL-8.0-Win10\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.24)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

Comment: can you explain what you did prior to the error copied some files? and did you make a backup that you can restore

Comment: I have no backup, I just installed the plugin on wordpress, restarted the server and it gives this error.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally recover the base from the files.

1. I downloaded the MySQL Workbench
2. I temporarily deleted the table files (.ibd) from server folder.
3. Started OpenServer, which had ib_logfile.
4. Connected to the database using the Workbench.
5. I returned the deleted table files.
6. In the Workbench choose Server > Data Export, get the database dump.
7. Then select all tables in Workbench (simply delete the entire database will not work) and drop tables.
8. Restore all the tables from the dump (Server > Data Import).